# int? not working for db nulls

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

So I thought the point of (int?) was to take an int or null if the db has null.  However I am getting an error

> Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

`VehicleGroupID` is the one giving the error because it is NULL in the database.  It is (int?) so it should be able to take in null values right? Isn't that the point of (int?)?  If not, what is the cleanest solution to allow nulls because there are actually a lot more nullable ints I have to get from the db.

Here is my code:

```
public int? VehicleClassID { get; set; }
public int? VehicleGroupID { get; set; }

public void getVehicleModelDetails ()
    {
        DataSet retVal = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection sqlConn = (SqlConnection)_context.Database.Connection;
        SqlCommand cmdReport = new SqlCommand("storedProc", sqlConn);
        SqlDataAdapter daReport = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdReport);
        using (cmdReport)
        {
            cmdReport.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            daReport.Fill(retVal);
        }

        // Set buyer vehicle details
        var row = retVal.Tables[0].Rows[0];
        VehicleClassID = (int?)row["VehicleClassID"];
        VehicleGroupID = (int?)row["VehicleGroupID"];
    }
```

FYI: I am using EF6, but the stored procedure returns custom data so I resorted to this.

Comment: Have you tried: `VehicleClassID = row.Field<int?>("VehicleClassID")`?

Comment: Good call! I am new to ASP.NET and I saw that this was the way the previous developer was doing it, so I assumed it was the correct way.  Your way is a much better solution though!  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my knowledge, `Field` extension method supports nullable types. So, below line should work as a charm:

```
VehicleClassID = row.Field<int?>("VehicleClassID");
```

Comment: Dude... I had seen this answer when looking for my solution online before, but I assumed they were using a different version than me or something because I did not know there was a Field method.  Yeah you are right, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks man!